# windows phone app, retrieve information from a website

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm working on an app that checks your gas mileage based on the numbers you give it. You can change from Km to miles and from litres to gallons. Now I am suppose to go to a website and grab the gas price of a state/province and show the user their price. There is a settings page where they can input their state/province and that's how it knows what to look for. I would like to be pointed in the right direction on how to go to a website and grab information from it.

These are the sites (one for states/one for provinces)

States = http://www.gasbuddy.com/GB_Price_List.aspx?cntry=USA

provinces = http://www.gasbuddy.com/GB_Price_List.aspx?cntry=CAN

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: just FYI there is a gasbuddy app for WP: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/gasbuddy/c40743d9-8fd5-df11-a844-00237de2db9e

Comment: I have seen that, thanks for the tip though. I need to learn how to do this in order to finish my app, the application I'm making is to teach myself and later on others. For every thing I do I make a tutorial on how to do it afterwards.

Comment: have a look at HttpWebRequest, it gets html of the site, you can split format or vs. with this result and get your informations.

Comment: Well first you need to download the HTML content of the URL. You can google how to do that, it's easy. And then you need to analyze the HTML data, you can do that manually, or use something like HTML Agility Pack to help you out. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Cool, I guess I have been trying to do everything in one step. That is why I could never find any good information. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: If you do this just for educational purpose be advised that grabbing and **parsing the HTML of a website is not a very robust way of consuming 3rd party data**. You have no guarantee that the website will not change over time and even small optical changes might break your code. Consider using a provider that offers a `Web API` of some sort.

Comment: You do raise a valid point. The point of these tutorials is to help people learn how to do things, hopefully if this does occur they will still understand the concepts and code in order to achieve the same result in their own situation.